# Is there a way to generate a single JS file using Webpack instead of main.bundle.css and main.bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, bundle, webpack-4

Currently, my **yarn build** script generates 2 files, main.[hash].js and main.[hash].css. Is there any way that I can bundle even my css file to the main.[hash].js so that I only have one js file?

Here are my config files:

webpack.common.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js',
        vendor: './src/vendor.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'imgs',
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                options: {
                    cache: true,
                    emitWarning: true,
                    failOnError: true,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        }),
    ],
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/template.html',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contentHash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/template.html',
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: '[name].[contentHash].css'}),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Extract css into files
          'css-loader', // 2. Turns css into commonjs
          'sass-loader', // 1. Turns sass into css
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

I have also tried adding some plugins to achieve this but had not had any luck so far.
If there is a plugin or some other way that you have, please help me with it.

Comment: Why do you want to bundle your CSS into JS? However, I would suggest that you should change your CSS loader(s) if you want to achieve that. Are you using extract css plugin?

Comment: You can't have the css in the js file annd have it work in the browser, if that is what you mean? What would be the reason for wanting to have it in the same file?

Comment: It is because I am working on a widget and I only want to host one file on my CDN, similar to what [UserWay](https://userway.org/) does. They just give you one JS file that you can include to your HTML file. I don't want to tell the user to include 2 different files in their HTML. Okay, I will try your suggestion of using that plugin.

Comment: Post your webpack config.